# Why do I only find two-handed magical weapons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I play an Imperial type character, that focuses on magic and one-handed war axes.

Whenever I go on assignments or into dungeons I only ever find two-handed enchanted weapons. I thought this was random and that I just have bad luck, but I then made the test and reloaded one dungeon countless times (before entering it!) and it always gave me a different two-handed weapon. It's getting annoying as I can never use the stuff I find.

So what influences what type of weapon you find? Race perharps? Or maybe which location is visited?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You can always just take the two-handed weapon home, disenchant it, and then put the enchantment on your own one-handed weapon.  Of course, the new enchantment won't be quite as strong until you level up enchanting quite a bit.

Comment: Lots of loot weapons are "random leveled one-handed enchanted weapon" or "random leveled greatsword" so if repetition yields you the same type of weapon you just need to go somewhere new.

Comment: Not an answer, but at level 27 I just picked up 3 1 handed elven battle axes with different magic enchantments on them.  My character of course is a two-handed weapons warrior.  Wanna trade? :)

Comment: Just speculation but if it is location based or quest based (eg. Companions quest) and the item type was fixed, with random bonuses, then reloading one save would always give you that item type. Honestly though on my character I find I use either items I have smithed myself (quite enjoying that), or items from the merchants. I've yet to come accross dungeon loot that really outshines some of the random magic items from merchants. Except perhaps the rare necklace or ring.

Comment: I believe the 2nd comment from agf is describing what is happening best. Through trial and error I also found, that the race and equipment you have does not seem to influence what you find.

Answer (score 2):

**your loot is random generated in most cases with some special items being set or fixed loot tied to a location or quest/person. i have tried the same save first then enter,then reenter to see if the loot changed and this didn't change the trigger but entering a different dungeon then reentering did reset the loot trigger. Random but would suggest you stop wearing your enchanted helmet of " give me crap i can't use " : P
as a consolation here is a link to a invisable chest ingame that you can loot every 2 days,crap loads of stuff including specials like what your looking for and does NOT trigger stolen...

hope this consolation prize eases your bad luck,but i wish you luck in future quests : )

Comment: I can confirm your assumptions of what triggers loot to be determined. It works that way for me too.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned it is based on luck. I suggest you visit different locations from time to time, not because you'll have better chances somewhere else (you might, but I'm not sure if this kind of data is available yet) but you may get frustrated faster if you keep doing the same area over and over. Distracting yourself with different environments might make it seem like you found the item you were looking for faster (if ever). Good luck!